# alternative to "no later than"

Tags: prepositional-phrases

*no later than* is often regarded as the alternative to *by*, as in :

> You should come back **no later than / by** 10 p.m

I'm wondering whether *no later than* can be used in the following way:

> Everyone should work **no later than** 10 p.m. today because there will be a
>   curfew tonight.

Do you think it should be replaced by *until*?
I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: Here the stress is that , no one should work beyond 10.  p.m. if you use until, it just implies people are supposed to work till the mentioned time. But you need to ensure they don't continue after 10. So until doesn't fit the context. 'no later than' or ' beyond' will suit appropriately.

Comment: How do you feel about: *Everyone should work by 10 p.m. today because there will be a curfew tonight*?

Comment: //Everyone should work no later than 10 p.m. today because there will be a curfew tonight// should be something like this: //No one should work any later than X today because the curfew goes into effect at X+1.// That said,  you can say what you like: No one should work later than x because of the curfew goes into effect at x+1.

Answer (score 1):

"Until" means the action is continuing at least up to the specific time or event. So "Everyone should work **until** 10 p.m. today because there will be a curfew tonight" doesn't really make sense because you're saying that everyone should work at least up to 10 p.m. or later, but no one should stop working before 10 p.m. Basically you're doing the opposite of observing the curfew.

On the other hand, "Everyone should work **no later than** 10 p.m. today because there will be a curfew tonight" sets 10 p.m. as the latest time for work, i.e. that a person could stop working any time before 10 p.m., but they cannot continue working after that time. You correctly surmised that "by" would also substitute for "no later than" without changing the meaning.

Answer (score 0):

**'at or before'**

For singular events, like your first example, you can say:

> You should come back at or before 10 p.m

It would be normal to just say 'before 10pm', because there case where someone comes back *exactly* at 10pm is usually not worth worrying about.

For continuous actions like your second example you can either convert to a singular event, like

> Everyone should finish work at or before 10 p.m. today because there will be a curfew tonight.

or you can use **'only until'**

> Everyone should work only until 10 p.m. today

Comment: Do you find the original sentence with "no later than" natural in the context?

Comment: @Apollyon no, the original sentence is unusable.